# Matrix Multiplication under a Modulo

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

Let $a$ and $b$ be different non-singular square matrices (same dimenstions) where all values are between 0 - 15

Let $c$ = $a.b$ mod 16 (all values in matrix are changed to mod 16)

Will $a^{-1}.c=b$?

or will taking mod 16 of $c$ change that value? I tested it with 5 cases and it turned out true, even if $c$ had values above 15. But I'm not sure how to prove it true for every case.

Comment: Nothing you said about $a$ implies that it would necessarily *have* an inverse $a^{-1}$. Did you want to assume that $a$ is an invertible matrix?

Comment: yes I forgot to mention that $a$ is non-singular

Comment: "Non-singular square matrices..." over **what** ring or field are these matrices non-singular?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, I just mean that these matrices have an inverse

Comment: @Vikestep: Where can the entries of your matrices come from? For example, if you require the entries of all your matrices to be integers, the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
would ***not*** be invertible, so this is an important issue.

Comment: ahh yes, all values are integers (I kept forgetting some stuff I assumed), so in that case, that matrix can't be $a$ or $b$, but if it was another square matrix which has an inverse, then that is fine

Comment: @VikeStep, the entries of matrices are chosen from some algebraic structure and they are invertible (non-sigular, regular) over this alg. structure ...*or not* . In the example given by Zev above the matrix is NOT invertible over the ring $\,\Bbb Z\,$ , yet it is invertible over the rationals $\,\Bbb Q\,$

Comment: If the ordinary inverse of the matrix has integer entries, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Then, if you require your matrices to be integer ones *and invertible* over the integesr they are regular iff their determinant is $\,\pm 1\,$ ...

Comment: ok to clear this up, it is over the rationals Q, and all the values are integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're going for, this is a counterexample to your conjecture. Let $a$ and $b$ be the integer matrices $$a=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 9 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\qquad b=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 7 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
which have determinant $1$, and hence are invertible no matter where you consider them. Then $$c=a\cdot b\bmod 16= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 9 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 7 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\bmod 16=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 16 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\bmod 16=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$$
but
$$a^{-1}\cdot c=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -9 \\ 0 & \hphantom{-}1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -9 \\ 0 & \hphantom{-}1
\end{bmatrix}\neq \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 7 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=b$$
(though of course, **modulo $\bf 16$**, these are the same; that is, $a^{-1}\cdot c\equiv b\bmod 16$.)

Comment: @FixedPoint: The statement $$a^{-1}\cdot c=b$$ is **different** from the statement $$a^{-1}\cdot c\equiv b\bmod 16.$$ Which one do you mean?

Comment: hmm well the reason I am asking is because i'm trying to use matrices for cryptography and assign each value a colour (there are 16 colours) so that you can encrypt and decrypt a picture. I can just make the final answer $b$ in mod 16 and it should work then?